# Permission denied to access property "invoke"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, angular

I'm running a Rails 5/Angular 2 integration test and getting the following error:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
>
> Permission denied to access property "invoke"

I'm not really sure even where to begin debugging. Any help would be appreciated.

Stack trace:

```
1) Books list page                                                                                                                [88/1823]
   Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('Books')

 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
   Permission denied to access property "invoke"
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:32:in `initialize'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:85:in `new'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:85:in `create_response'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:107:in `request'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:63:in `call'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:640:in `raw_execute'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:615:in `execute'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:345:in `execute_script'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:215:in `execute_script'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/selenium/node.rb:9:in `all_text'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:61:in `block in text'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:81:in `synchronize'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/node/element.rb:59:in `text'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/node/document.rb:24:in `text'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/queries/text_query.rb:81:in `text'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/queries/text_query.rb:60:in `build_message'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/queries/text_query.rb:25:in `failure_message'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:562:in `block in assert_text'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:650:in `block in _verify_text'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:648:in `_verify_text'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:560:in `assert_text'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:721:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/rspec/matchers.rb:93:in `block in matches?'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/rspec/matchers.rb:24:in `wrap_matches?'
 # /Users/jasonswett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/rspec/matchers.rb:93:in `matches?'
 # ./spec/features/books_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Feature test code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Books', js: true do
  scenario 'list page' do
    visit '/'
    expect(page).to have_content('Books')
  end
end
```

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace as well as the code where the exception occurs.

Comment: without you code. No help can be rendered to get appreciated. Add the code as said

Comment: Updated to include stack trace and some code.

Comment: Have you set Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements=false or Capybara.visible_text_only=true for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Update your UI component dependencies (`package.json`) to depend on `zone.js` version 0.8.7 or higher

```
{
    "zone.js": ">=0.8.7"
}
```

[Source issue on angular github](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/616).