# Firefox: Permission denied to access property "invoke"

Tags: python, angular, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am running a script with Selenium Webdriver with Python for an Angular 2 based web application. The script works perfectly well when I use it with `webdriver.Chrome`. However, when I use `webdriver.Firefox`, I get an error `Permission denied to access property "invoke"`. I am using Selenium 3.4.1, Firefox 53.0.2 (32-bit), Geckodriver 0.16.1, and Python 2.7. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683093/permission-denied-to-access-property-invoke/44457576